# jquery submit form with ajax after click div element

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, click, submit

i have troubles to get work this script. I want to sent a form as ajax by trigger submit after click a div element.

This is the form code:

```
<div title="add to Favorits" id="social1549" class="favtrigger nobtn transition">
    <form name="favoritform" id="formsocial1549" action="/dienstleister/fotografen/1549/verlobungsfotos-im-studio-hochzeitsfotografie" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="favorit" value="1549">
        <div id="submitsocial1549" class="layout">
            <div class="favicon_off"></div>
            <p>as Favorit</p>
        </div>    
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is the jquery code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.favtrigger').click(function() {
            var favid = $(this).attr('id');
            var form = $(this).find('#form' + favid);
            alert ('until here it works'); // this works
            form.submit(function(event) {
                alert ('this doesn't work'); // here nothing happens
                event.preventDefault();
                var action = form.attr('action'),
                    method = form.attr('method'),
                    data = form.serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: action,
                    type: method,
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data) {
                        var data = $('#' + favid + ' .layout', data);
                        $('#' + favid + ' .layout').replaceWith(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: try to trigger the submit too - only setting a ".on('submit'.." doesnt call it. Add a submit() after it

Comment: tried, it now makes a submit, but without ajax.

Comment: and you called the submit after you set the .on('submit'.. ?

Comment: i tried like this series: on.('click), submit(), on.submit(func.. otherwise with submit() after on.submit, nothing happens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need to submit the form if you're using it only to retrieve the action link. I would take off the form submit entirely.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.favtrigger', function() {
        var favid = $(this).attr('id');
        var form = $(this).find('#form' + favid);
        var action = form.attr('action'),
            method = form.attr('method'),
            data = form.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            type: method,
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                var data = $('#' + favid + ' .layout', data);
                $('#' + favid + ' .layout').replaceWith(data);
            }
        });

    });
});
```